# Android OpenGL SurfaceHolder Callbacks

Tags: android, opengl-es, callback, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

The [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html)  state that for **surfaceCreated**, **surfaceChanged** and **surfaceDestroyed**:

> This method is part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface, and is not normally called or subclassed by clients of GLSurfaceView

However, they *are* called in my (OpenGL ES 2.0) app.

This is the order of things in my App

**App Launched**

- surfaceCreate
- surfaceChanged
- onSurfaceCreated

**Now I press Home key *before* onSurfaceChanged is called, so app is now in the background**

- surfaceDestroyed
- onSurfaceChanged

So, as you can see, according to the above, the surface is **destroyed** and then it is changed - obviously this is impossible.

The app works fine.  I can then re-launch it and everything works.

I'm just a little confused.  My guess is that **surfaceCreated**, **surfaceChanged** and **surfaceDestroyed** *are* called, but have no effect on my GLSurfaceView.

Can anyone confirm this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have misunderstood the documentation. It is not saying that these methods are not called. With emphasis added:

> is not normally called or subclassed **by clients** of GLSurfaceView

What this is telling you is that if you use the `GLSurfaceView` class, which makes you a client, you are not supposed to call these methods. In addition, if you subclass `GLSurfaceView`, they do not recommend that you override these methods.

In other words, these methods are intended for internal use. They are called, but you should normally leave it up to the `GLSurfaceView` to handle the calls. As a user of `GLSurfaceView`, you should not worry about these methods at all, and use the recommended and well documented methods when you subclass `GLSurfaceView`, and interact with instances of `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: Put another way: GLSurfaceView is a SurfaceView with some helper code wrapped around it.  It really should be part of a "support library" rather than mixed in with the framework classes.  If you "steal" the callbacks from the GLSurfaceView implementation you're going to have a bad time.  See also https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html .